# Altair: How to start a interactive nominal bar chart at a predefined zoom?

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I'm using Altair to build a simple vertical bar chart. It has a lot of nominal columns and I've called `interactive()` at the end so I can do zoom and panning.

How do I start the scale zoomed so that it starts displaying just the leftmost 10 columns?

I managed to display just the 10 first columns, but it prevents me to pan:

```
sorted_values = df.sort_values('nota', ascending=False)['CO_ESCOLA'].values
(alt.Chart(df).mark_bar()
 .encode(x=alt.X("CO_ESCOLA:N", 
                 sort=sorted_values, 
                 scale=alt.Scale(domain=sorted_values[:10])), 
         y="nota:Q")
 .properties(width=1000)
 .interactive()
)
```

Comment: Nominal axes do not support panning and zooming, so I don't think there is any way to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and amazing lib @jakevdp , I think I've find an alternative solution for my problem and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, @japevdp gave the definitive answer for what I asked: it is impossible to pan in a nominal axis.

But exploring Altair, I arrived at a nice solution for my problem that I'd like to share.

My problem was that I have too many columns and would like to display all of them while also allowing the user to drill down.

Setting the bar size and the step between the bars, I've created a very large chart, and the notebook automatically created a horizontal scroll bar. I usually shrug to horizontal scroll, but it allows the user to analyze a subset of the data.

[image: Bar chart with horizontal scroll]

And the `interative()` method still allows me to zoom in the y axis:

[image: Zoomed bar chart]

I think it is a good solution. Here is the code:

```
(alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(size=30)
 .encode(x=alt.X("CO_ESCOLA:N", sort=df.sort_values('nota_final', ascending=False)['CO_ESCOLA'].values), 
         y="nota_final:Q", tooltip=['nota_final'])
 .properties( width=alt.Step(45))
 .interactive()
)
```

The key points are the `width=30` and `width=alt.step(45)` options.
Here is the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on altair, but your question enlightened me to do some research. It does not seem to be possible to move it left or right in a bar chart. The user selection feature can highlight the selection by changing the color of the selection while showing the whole graph image. If this technique does not fit your visualization scenario, you can dismiss my answer. The code was adapted from [this](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/select_mark_area.html) one in the official reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import random, string

def randomname(n):
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=n))

df = pd.DataFrame({'nota':np.random.randint(0,50,(30,))})
df['CO_ESCOLA'] = df['nota'].apply(lambda x:randomname(5))

sorted_values = df.sort_values('nota', ascending=False)['CO_ESCOLA'].values
base = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(
    color='steelblue',
    opacity=0.3,
).encode(
    x=alt.X("CO_ESCOLA:N",
            sort=sorted_values,
            scale=alt.Scale(domain=sorted_values)
           ),
    y=alt.Y("nota:Q",
            )#scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,55])
).properties(
    width=1000
)

text = base.mark_text(align='center',
                      baseline='middle',
                      color='yellow',
                      dy=10
).encode(
    text='nota:Q'
)

brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'],empty='all')# _interval
background = base.add_selection(brush)
selected = base.transform_filter(brush).mark_bar(color='steelblue')

alt.layer(background, selected, text).interactive()
```

[image]